# Invert tab scrolling direction with mouse scroll button in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

When using the Google Chrome, you can scroll over your tabs when you hover your mouse over them and then scroll with the scroll button.

My problem is that I'd like to reverse the way it scrolls through the tabs. I just don't know how.

For instance, when you scroll your mouse wheel up it scrolls to the first tab. I want it to scroll to the last tab and vice versa.

Comment: This isn't the exact method you're looking for, but I choose to cycle through my tabs with `CTRL+Tab` and backwards with `CTRL+SHIFT+Tab`